# Jenkins TFS Plugin error: Querying for remote changeset at ... Query returned no result

Tags: jenkins, tfs

I got this error when I try to build a project in TFS. Is there a way to make it download the latest copy even there is no change?

```
Building remotely on public_jendevslave_1 in workspace D:\public_jendevslave_1\workspace\DevOps\SonarQube-PLSQL-TFS
[WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...
[WS-CLEANUP] Done
Querying for remote changeset at '$/Server Artifacts/Schedule Snapshot 2013/SQL/EDBDEV/ACCT/PROCEDURE' as of 'D2016-02-04T20:32:42Z'...
Query returned no result!
FATAL: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start the build, it's supposed to get the latest changeset for your project. With the configuration shows in following screenshot, I can get the latest version. You may change your Project path to `$/teamprojectname/projectname` to see whether you can get the latest version.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was able to proceed using another account. Guess it's an access issue, just the error message was missing leading.